# W3C Doctype Error?

Tags: xhtml

My site uses this DTD in the  which is the correct one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb">
```

But I keep getting this validation error on the W3C site?

```
 DOCTYPE Override in effect!

The detected DOCTYPE Declaration "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">" has been suppressed and the DOCTYPE for "XHTML + RDFa" inserted instead, but even if no errors are shown below the document will not be Valid until you update it to reflect this new DOCTYPE.
```

Any suggestions on what's going on here and how do I fix it?

Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have changed the "Document Type" preference in the UI for the Markup Validation Service from *(detect automatically)* to *XHTML + RFDa*.

This causes the validator to comment out the existing Doctype and insert the one you selected. It does not first check if the existing Doctype is the same as the one you selected.

To remove the warning, put the preference back to *(detect automatically)*

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The website W3C validation is a re-driect from a well known online SEO system - so their link obviously strips out the DTD and enters it manually which causes it to fail 100% validation. Interesting bug!!